# Identifying traversal order in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I am curious about how Neo4j determines what traversal order i.e BFS or DFS to use on receiving a query. From a query description, how does it determine that a BFS or DFS traversal order would be beneficial. I would suspect it would happen during the query evaluation phase but I have not seen any documentation. Any suggestions or links to understand this would be quite useful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use EXPLAIN to see the operations how your query would be processed.

It is not directly BFS or DFS but can have multiple starting points etc.

In general the Expand(All) operation chained is DFS. But there is also a bi-directional ExpandInto and several types of Joins and Apply's.

see: http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/execution-plans.html

Comment: Thanks for the response. In the link provided, I feel the place where the compiler would apply a traversal order would be in the expand operators as this is where the graph is explored from the staring nodes identified. Based on your comment about the expand all operator using DFS, there can be cases where BFS would be more appropriate than DFS. So, does Neo4J identify some stats to make that decision or is it default DFS? Thanks.

Comment: We're adding more options there. Do you have concrete examples where BFS would be beneficial? It takes more memory to run BFS (esp on dense nodes) so we usually favor DFS